# Design an algorithm with network flow

Tags: algorithms

Given a matrix A with 0 and 1 entries. Neighbours of a[i,j] are a[i-1,j], a[i+1,j], a[i,j-1] and a[i,j+1] (if exists any).

Tow neigbour entries are an Improper pair if they have not equal values.
if number of **improper** pair of matrix A equals to q, then the penalty of matrix will be equals to b*q (which b is a natural number).

Before computing the penalty, we can **inverse** some of entries (0 -> 1 or 1 -> 0) with cost of a (for each entry inversion). The goal is **minimizing the sum of inversion cost and final penalty**; An algorithm (with help of network flow) should be proposed for this goal.

My Idea for start:
I assume each entry a node, then create a node s, and connect it to all 0 entries.
Then create a node t, and connect all 1 entries to it.

Comment: is that your homework ?

Comment: @c69 No! It's part of a bigger problem that I should solve for my work

Comment: @AshKan - not your fault, but you'd be amazed how many homework assignments get cut & pasted in here with little or no thought.  We usually ask them to read [Open letter to students with homework](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166/64132) so they understand why they need to think the problem through for themselves.  Since yours is not a homework problem, perhaps you could elaborate with a sample matrix or two and possibly explain how this fits into the bigger problem (so we're not facing an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218240))